# Shapely contains(point) always gives False

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I started working on geopandas and shapely today and I am trying to use the `contains` method to check if a point lies inside a polygon of geological constituency data from [here](http://projects.datameet.org/maps/assembly-constituencies/#issues). My code is:

```
if janak.boundary.contains(cent_janak):
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')
```

where `janak` is a polygon from geometry data of a shapefile and `cent_janak` is the centroid of janak.
To verify, I plotted them like this

```
from descartes import PolygonPatch
BLUE = '#6699cc'
poly= janak
fig = plt.figure() 
ax = fig.gca() 
ax.add_patch(PolygonPatch(poly, fc=BLUE, ec=BLUE, alpha=0.5, zorder=2 ))

ax.axis('scaled')
plt.plot(cjx, cjy, 'bo')
plt.show()
```

The resulting plot is this. [image]

For more clarity `janak.boundary.coords.xy` polygon coords are:

```
(array('d', [77.27673511633259, 77.28194987388764, 77.29578190561051, 77.27662755381863, 77.25524963905963, 77.2580696782731, 77.26521771742375, 77.26932536547332, 77.26832967477475, 77.27477975458208, 77.27673511633259]),
 array('d', [28.540205606503605, 28.52730150785834, 28.495644714432103, 28.493054206486477, 28.506460566601902, 28.521859125598212, 28.525798083314953, 28.52190443074494, 28.540396930973657, 28.544344420558616, 28.540205606503605]))
```

The centroid `cent_janak.coords.xy` coords are:

```
(array('d', [77.27464056229368]), array('d', [28.51348721728798]))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `janak.boundary.contains(cent_janak)`, you are asking if `cent_janak` lies *on* the boundary. The method you are looking for is simply `janak.contains(cent_janak)`.