# Checking if LinearRing contains a point always returns False in Shapely

Tags: python, shapely

This is variation of [Shapely contains(point) always gives False](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53654056/shapely-containspoint-always-gives-false), not a duplicate

I want to determine if a point inside a certain figure created of many points, but to start simple I do this test, which fails. I define a 2x2 square, and the first point should be inside, the second outside, but both calls return `False`

```py
import unittest
from shapely.geometry import LineString,Point,LinearRing
class TestTools(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_isInside(self):
        points = [
            [0,0],
            [2,0],
            [2,2],
            [0,2]
        ]
        ring=LinearRing(points)
        print(ring)
        print(Point(1,2))
        self.assertEqual(ring.contains(Point(1,1)),True) 
        self.assertEqual(ring.contains(Point(3,3)),False)
```

The output is

```
LINEARRING (0 0, 2 0, 2 2, 0 2, 0 0)
POINT (1 2)
======================================================================
FAIL: test_isInside (__main__.TestTools)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_tools.py", line 17, in test_isInside
    self.assertEqual(ring.contains(Point(1,1)),True)
AssertionError: False != True
```

So obviously I'm doing something (simple?) wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Shapely documentation](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#spatial-data-model) there are three fundamental types of geometric objects: points, curves, and surfaces. The `LinearRing` is one of the implementations of the curve type.

Citing the docs:

> A *Curve* has an *interior* set consisting of the infinitely many points along its length (imagine a *Point* dragged in space), a *boundary* set consisting of its two end points, and an *exterior* set of all other points. A *Curve* has a topological dimension of 1.

And here is what it says about [`object.contains(other)`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#object.contains) method:

> Returns `True` if no points of *other* lie in the exterior of the *object* and at least one point of the interior of *other* lies in the interior of *object*.

So, in your case the points `Point(1, 1)`, `Point(3, 3)` don't lie on the curve `LinearRing([[0, 0], [2, 0], [2, 2], [0, 2]])` but outside it, in the exterior, hence your tests return `False`.

In order to check if the points are enclosed by the `LinearRing`, in your simple case, you could construct [polygons](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#polygons) from those rings and do the same check:

```
>>> Polygon(ring).contains(Point(1, 1))
True

>>> Polygon(ring).contains(Point(3, 3))
False
```